# What is the difference between /user, /base and something like /people domains?

Tags: freebase, mql

I see that there are several types listed under a particular domain, but I see that the domains are either starting with `/user`, `/base` or something more meaningful like `/music` OR `/people`. What is the basic difference between having a type in one of these three types?

Does `/user` mean someone has created this domain? If so, then what is `/base`? I do understand the `/people`.. `/music` kind of domains which have a vast number of topics inside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to review the wiki pages for [Domains](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Domains), [Commons](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Commons) and [Bases](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Base).

Yes, all /user/foo/... types were created by /user/foo.  Domains which are bases can vary from experimental efforts which contain almost nothing to large well populated bases like my base for the U.S. [National Register of Historic Places](http://www.freebase.com/view/base/usnris) which contains almost 40,000 topics.

Comment: Thanks. I just read the documentation. So it means that a domain is basically a group of types. Now, if the types is created by a user "foo", then it would start with the path /user/foo. Also, there are a set of types and properties that are well documented and standardized and this group of types and properties are termed as the commons domain. So, it would mean a type would either be in the base domain or the commons domain, right?